# get_template_part for custom post type content not working

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, loop

I have a custom post type of **Textorial** with necessary template files:

1. textorial-type.php
2. single-textorial.php
3. content-textorial.php

The idea is to have a custom layout for the post type and use infinite-scroll to pull them in. That's why I'm using content.php. I got the infinite-scroll set up,and succesfully tested with regular posts. But when pulling custom post type in on index.php:

```
<div id="content">
<?php 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', 'textorial' );                    
    endwhile;   
?>
</div>
```

... nothing shows up. Also no errors. But the single-textorial.php is using the same method and its content is showing. Any ideas?

**Update!**

on front-page.php:

```
<?php $args = array('post_type' => 'textorial');
                $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                while (have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    get_template_part( 'content', 'textorial' );
                endwhile; 
              ?>
```

But now only regular posts show up.

Comment: Did you use `pre_get_posts` to set your custom post type in the main query. Also, what is `texorial-type.php`

Comment: I don't follow you when say main query, you are looking at the main query. Doesn't it know to pick up textorial post-type without it? textorial-type.php is the file where I declare the custom post type and control its parameters.

Comment: Ha, that confused me, so `textorial-type.php` is like a `functions.php` file. Remember, custom post types are excluded from the main query

Comment: Yeah, I keep them separate for code reading purposes. I tried query know, please see update.

Comment: On which specific page/template are you trying this

Comment: Right now, front-page.php.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20630/discussion-between-laniakea-and-pieter-goosen).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of issues with your code.

- You have to set your loop to your custom query. As it stands, it is set to the main query
- You must always reset postdata with all instances of `WP_Query`

Your code should be something like this

```
<?php $args = array('post_type' => 'textorial');
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ($query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    get_template_part( 'content', 'textorial' );

endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Yeah, custom posts are now showing up. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Glad it worked. Enjoy :-)